# Stack android push notifications in parse unity

Tags: android, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I have push notifications set up which work, however when the user has multiple notifications I would like to combine them into one summary notification.

Does anyone know what I have to do to achieve this? I haven't been able to find any examples of this being done using Unity.

My best guess is that I have to basically make my own copy of [ParsePushUnityHelper.java](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/blob/f577ee38a0d55a199a473065b18acad084e4b083/ParsePush/Native/src/main/java/com/parse/ParsePushUnityHelper.java), compile it into a .dll which I then add as a Unity Native Plugin, then hook that up in a similar way to [PushBehaviour.cs](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/blob/16d59f8b444ad902789e2206dcc9d93056c96b65/Parse.StarterProjects/CSharp/ParseUnityPushSample/Assets/PushBehaviour.cs), but that is a lot of work so I am hoping there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so basically what you need to do is create your own .jar using the contents of [this folder](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/tree/f577ee38a0d55a199a473065b18acad084e4b083/ParsePush/Native/src/main/java/com/parse), save a list of received notifications to update a notification with, then clear that list when the notification is opened or cleared.

For more info, check out the discussion I had with Parse developers [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/190).